# How to get the part of HTML code that I need JSON

Tags: javascript, android, html, json

reading some documents I saw that you can find, by jsoup (ANDROID), what i need in an html source. But it does not explain how to find exactly what I need. Eg:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var suburl = "blablablabla";
        </script>
```

How can I find EXACTLY what contains suburl?

Tnks.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following:

```
suburl.indexOf('lab') // returns 1
```

If the value in the indexOf(  ) is not found the result will be -1.

Comment: isn't what I need, I need the string which is contained in  var suburl